# [GLPK][Java] Problems with integer variable

Tags: java, linear-programming, glpk

I am working with Glpk java and I have to solve this problem (primal)

```
\* Problem: Branch and Bound Problem *\

Maximize
 z: + 0.5 x1 + 0.5 x2 + 0.333333333333333 x3 + 0.142857142857143 x4

Subject To
 c1: + 14 x4 + 31 x3 + 36 x2 + 45 x1 <= 100

Generals
 x1
 x2
 x3
 x4

End
```

I have this result

```
z = 1.3888888888888888
x1 = 0.0
x2 = 2.7777777777777777
x3 = 0.0
x4 = 0.0
```

But i only want Integer solution.
All my columns are set with

```
GLPK.glp_set_col_kind(lp, column, GLPKConstants.GLP_IV);
```

I solve it with : (edit)

```
public void solve_prim(){ 
        GLPK.glp_write_lp(lp,
                null,
                "lp.txt");
    parm = new glp_smcp();
    GLPK.glp_init_smcp(parm);

    ret = GLPK.glp_simplex(lp, parm);

    // Retrieve solution
    if (ret == 0) {
        write_lp_solution_prim(lp);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The problem could not be solved");
    }

    // Free memory
    GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
}
```

But I Always have fractionnal solution.
Someone has any idea ?

Comment: Show the code where you call the solver. (I suspect you call the simplex LP solver instead of the MIP solver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ret = GLPK.glp_simplex(lp, parm);
```

This calls the LP solver. You will get fractional results. To get integer results you need to call the MIP solver:

```
ret = GLPK.glp_intopt(lp, parm);
```